Monotonicity of a function concerning trigonometric functions
For $r\in(0,\pi)$ we write
$$
\alpha(r)=\frac{r^2}{1-r\cot r}
$$
and define the following function
$$
g(r):=\frac{-\alpha^{\prime}(r) \alpha(r)}{r}.
$$
My problem is how to show that $g$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi)$. I have tried to calculate its derivative in an elementary way, which, however, seems to be difficult to handle. So I'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach.

I agree with you that looking at the sign of$$g'(r)=\frac{\alpha (r) \left(\alpha '(r)-r
   \,\alpha ''(r)\right)-r\, \alpha'(r)^2}{r^2}$$ with
$$\alpha(r)=\frac{r^2}{1-r\cot( r)}$$
is not the most pleasant task.
What you could at least do is to first look at what happens close to $r=0$ using Taylor series.
Using
$$1-r\cot( r)=\frac{r^2}{3}+\frac{r^4}{45}+\frac{2 r^6}{945}+\frac{r^8}{4725}+\frac{2
   r^{10}}{93555}+O\left(r^{12}\right)$$ using long division
$$\alpha(r)=3-\frac{r^2}{5}-\frac{r^4}{175}-\frac{2 r^6}{7875}-\frac{37
   r^8}{3031875}+O\left(r^{10}\right)$$ leads to
$$g'(r)=-\frac{4 r}{175}-\frac{8 r^3}{875}-\frac{296 r^5}{202125}+O\left(r^7\right)$$ which is negative.
Without any expansion
$$g'(\pi)=-\pi$$
What would remains to prove is that $g''(r)$ is always negative
Edit
It happens that the series expansion of $g(r)$ around $r=0$ is very good for all the range  if we use a sufficient number of terms. Notice that beside the constant, all coefficients are negative (checked up to $m=100$) .
Let
$$S_m(r)=\sum_{n=0}^m a_n\, r^{2n}$$ and compute the infinite norm
$$\Phi_m=\int_0^\pi \Big(g(r)-S_m(r)\Big)^2\,dr$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & \Phi_m \\
 10 & 3.10421\times 10^{-5} \\
 20 & 1.13546\times 10^{-10} \\
 30 & 2.10152\times 10^{-16} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
So, I suppose that we can rely on the expansion built around $r=0$ and conclude that $g''(r)<0$.
If we do not accept, we need to prove that
$$2+r^2+r^4 \left(-4 r^2-5 r \cot(r)+4\right) \csc ^4(r)+$$ $$
r^2 \left(-2 r^4+19 r^2-8 \left(r^2-2\right) r
   \cot (r)-22\right) \csc ^2(r)+5 r\cot (r)$$ is always positive.
Have fun !

Thanks for your answer. But it seems that to show that $g''(r)<0$ is not easy. I don't know how to prove it briefly.

@William. Have a look at the edit.

Good observation! I understand the point. Thank you!
